# Одновременное выполнение процессов

Tags: c, unix

Я написал вот такой код. Задача заключалась в том, чтобы скачивать файл в процессе потомка, а в родителе запустить таймер, который выводил время каждые 3 секунды. Не могу понять как это сделать, ведь если вызвать wait то родитель будет ждать конца выполнения потомка, а мне надо реализовать там таймер.

```
int main(void) {
    int pid;
    int status;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Потомок\n");
        execl("/usr/bin/wget", "-P", "--limit-rate=300k" ,"https://muff.kiev.ua/files/books/OS_UNIX_RUS.pdf", NULL);
    } else {
        // timer
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

Comment: вам надо написать обработчик для сигнала CHLD и вызывать wait из него, после чего установить признак его отработки в какой нибудь глобальной переменной. А в той точке где у вас сейчас написан wait сделать собственно таймер, видимо sleep в цикле (который будет завершаться по установке признака обработчиком CHLD) и вывод времени.

Comment: @Mike спасибо, все получилось, сразу не додумался сделать обработчик)